# org.jboss.seam.RequiredException: @In attribute requires non-null value: selectAccountPageBean.accountSessionBean

Tags: java, jboss, seam

The "Caused by:" section of my stack trace says:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.seam.RequiredException: 
@In attribute requires non-null value: selectAccountPageBean.accountSessionBean
```

The Page-scoped bean has this:

```
@Name("selectAccountPageBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
public class SelectAccountPageWidgetBean 
    extends BaseWidgetBean implements Serializable
{
...
    @In(create = true)
    private AccountSessionBean accountSessionBean;
...
}
```

The Session-scoped bean has this:

```
@Name("accountSessionBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
public class AccountSessionBean implements Serializable
{
...
}
```

When I refer to the Page-scoped bean from a facelet, I get the error.

I've done this same thing in other apps and it worked fine.  Is there some configuration value that I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which change fixed it, but we did two things.

1. We added in a components.properties file.  Someone suggested that we should have one on
   the classpath even if it's empty.
2. We had a problem with the package that the component was in.  The package structure was 
   something like:

   ```
   foo.bar.baz
   ```

   But the component was in a directory like:

   ```
   foo/bar/pirate/monkey/baz
   ```

We simply moved the file to the proper directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once by simply misspelling the bean name in the facelet. Can you include the facelet code as well ?

Comment: Correction ... actually it turned out that I had some EL in a query that was referencing a @Factory tag in another bean...it was a cut and paste straggler ... fixed the EL reference and I was good to go.